Can I remove all special tokens from text if I want to use it for LLM continuous pretraining
I want to use text data for for LLM continuous pretraining. I have a bunch of instruction tuning datasets for that purpose. Some of them have text with special tokens like:
[ { "from": "human", "value": "some question" }, { "from": "gpt", "value": "answer" } ]

Should I clean it before using it for LLM continuous pretraining?
As I know, LLM can learn special tokens and reproduce them in text generation after pretraining. That's why text often is cleaned from html tags etc.
On the other side, for fine-tuning purposes special tokens helps LLM to learn instructions.
Is it similar to LLM continuous pretraining purposes or I should clean text to get better text generation quality?
